# How to create a cron which finds/kills/clears old puppet runs?

Tags: bash, command-line, find, cron, kill

I am a new user of bash/cron, and I was given a task to create a cron which finds/kill/ and clears old puppet runs that were not successfully installed. The more help the better, but I am more or less looking for a starting point. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for help making a cronjob, or help with finding a command to kill old puppet runs?

Comment: help with finding a command to kill old puppet runs

Answer (score 1):

Your command line could be:

```
pidof puppet | sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]* //' | while read p; do kill -9 $p; done
```

where:

- `pidof` gets the list of `puppet` processes running
- `sort -n`, sorts in descending order
- `sed` preserves the last puppet runs
- the `while` loop gets the output from those commands and passes them to the `kill` command.